# Android notificación listener

Tags: android, android-notifications

Me gustaría saber si es posible redirigir al usuario a la aplicación luego de que active el permiso de notificaciones. Estoy utilizando:

`Intent intent=new Intent("android.settings.NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS");`

> Una vez activado el permiso quiero que vuelva a mi aplicación.

Comment: en teoría si presionas back debería regresar a tu aplicación , no funciona? como lo estás llamando?

Comment: Claro, con back funciona. Pero no es lo que deseo hacer. Quiero que sea de forma automática una vez que activo el permiso. Para evitar que el usuario piense como volver.

Comment: lo unico es mostrarle una notificación y al hacer click en ella enviarlo a la tu app ...

Comment: "Para evitar que el usuario piense como volver.", en realidad eso ya lo pensó Google por esa razón realizo este diseño, el usuario entra a una configuración de su aplicación y lo que realiza para salir (en caso de no existir un botón para esta acción) es dar clic en el botón "back", "regresar", etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma correcta para abrir los settings relacionados a la notificación es:

```
   Intent intent=new Intent("android.settings.APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS");
   intent.putExtra("app_package", getPackageName());
   intent.putExtra("app_uid", getApplicationInfo().uid);
   // Usado para Android O
   intent.putExtra("android.provider.extra.APP_PACKAGE", getPackageName());

   startActivity(intent);
```

en este caso abres los settings de la aplicación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Lo que deseas en este punto es que regrese a tu aplicación una vez activado el permiso, en realidad no existe ningún listener para determinar alguna acción en este caso.**

Pero hay algo importante que debes saber, si abres los settings de las notificaciones de tu aplicación, **en realidad los settings se abren siempre sobre la aplicación**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso la acción normal es dar clic en el botón de regreso y volverás a tu aplicación.